# Wicked lease file

Tags: opensuse, dhcp

Sorry for the probably silly question but I'm new to openSUSE and Wicked tool. I have an XML lease file and I don't quite understand the purpose of some tags.

```
<lease>
  <family>ipv4</family>
  <type>dhcp</type>
  <state>granted</state>
  ...

  <ipv4:dhcp>
    <server-id>[some IP address]</server-id>
    ...
    <boot>
      <server-address>[another IP address, different from the one under server-id]</server-address>
      <filename>[filename]</filename>
    </boot>
    <routes>
      <route>
        <nexthop>
          <gateway>[gateway]</gateway>
        </nexthop>
      </route>
    </routes>
    <dns>
      ...
    </dns>
  </ipv4:dhcp>
</lease>
```

I don't understand the meaning of `server-id` and `server-address` and what those addresses are used for. Currently, I searched after wicked lease and configurations but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Any help is appreciated!

Best Regards!

Comment: Do you also have a BOOTP server on the network? Do you use network booting?

Comment: Yes, in our network we have BOOTP and we use network booting. But in the client's network, we don't know if it has, but we parse the lease file to show the DHCP server IP.

Comment: The IP address in the `<boot>` section is likely to be the address of the BOOTP server, and the server ID thing is simply the IP address of the DHCP server, allowing the client to choose the most relevant lease if there are multiple DHCP servers on the network.  I won't turn this into an answer as I don't know much about DHCP.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks a lot. Cause in our software we parse the server address  from boot and show it in the UI. But this specific client complaint that he doesn't see the address but didn't told us his network configurations.